# Java problema al enviar paquete UDP en Hexadecimal protocolo VISCA

Tags: java, socket

Estoy haciendo un script (novato) que permita comunicarme usando el protocolo visca para comunicarme con una cámara PTZ, este protocolo funciona pasando un paquete UDP al puerto 5238 y usa comandos en hexadecimal. Pasando la cadena hexadecimal o en ASCII usando el programa packet sender, me funciona, con un script en python me funciona pasando:
data = bytes.fromhex("01 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 81 01 06 04 FF")
pero en java no logro pasar correctamente los datos,

```
package com.coveros.demo.helloworld;

import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class HelloWorld {

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] {(byte) 192, 168, 1, 1 };
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr);
    int port = 52381;
    //String data1 = "\\01\\00\\00\\05\\00\\00\\00\\00\\81\\01\\06\\04\\ff";
    //byte[] data1 = {01,00,00,05,00,00,00,00,81,01,06,04, FF};
    //String data2 = "010000050000000081010604ff";
    String data2 = "\\01\\00\\00\\05\\00\\00\\00\\00\\81\\01\\06\\04\\ff";    
    String str = new String(data2);
    byte[] byteArr = data2.getBytes();
    DatagramSocket datasoc = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket dpac = new DatagramPacket(byteArr, byteArr.length, ip, 52381);
    datasoc.send(dpac);
    datasoc.close();
  }
}
```

No entiendo qué esta pasando. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Muchas gracias a todos por adelantado y felices fiestas!!

Answer (score 0):

Al final encontré el problema:

Hay que convertir correctamente la cadena hexadecimal a bytes, encontré una función que permite hacerlo

```
  public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
      data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
              + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
  }
```